# IntelliJ organise imports removes org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is

Tags: grails, groovy, ide, junit, intellij-idea

I am currently writing a Grails app using IntelliJ.  Having migrated from Eclipse, I wanted to enable "organise imports".  If I understand correctly, I had to enable

> Settings | Editor | Auto Import | Optimize imports on the fly enabled

All is good, but IntelliJ keeps on removing

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is
```

that I use in my unit tests.  It probably does that since it thinks that I mean Groovy's "is", but it's wrong!  Any clues on how I prevent it from removing my static import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89633) that is already fixed in [IDEA 12 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP).